# How can I correctly initialize fixed length Char variables from a structure?

Tags: vb.net

I´m trying to initialize a struct from a class I have in my code. This is 3rd party class with little to none documentation for .NET, so I´m stuck in a initialization of some Char variables that were defined with a fixed length within a structure.

This is the structure from this 3rd part class.

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack:=4)> _
Public Structure ODBSYS
    Public addinfo As Short
    Public max_axis As Short
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public cnc_type As Char()
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public mt_type As Char()
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=4)> _
    Public series As Char()
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=4)> _
    Public version As Char()
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=2)> _
    Public axes As Char()
End Structure
```

And this is the function I´m working on:

```
Private Function GetControlInfo()
        Dim CNCSys As Focas1.ODBSYS
        CNCSys.addinfo = 0
        CNCSys.max_axis = 0
        CNCSys.cnc_type = ""
        CNCSys.mt_type = ""
        CNCSys.series = ""
        CNCSys.version = ""
        CNCSys.axes = ""

    Try

        intHandleNo = Focas1.cnc_sysinfo(LibHndl, CNCSys)

        MessageBox.Show("AddInfo: " & CNCSys.addinfo.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "MaxAxis: " & CNCSys.max_axis.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "CNCType: " & CNCSys.cnc_type.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "MTType: " & CNCSys.mt_type.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "Series: " & CNCSys.series.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "Version: " & CNCSys.version.ToString & vbCrLf & _
       "Axes: " & CNCSys.axes.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

If I don´t add this variable initialization code right after the creation of CSys:

```
        CNCSys.addinfo = 0
        CNCSys.max_axis = 0
        CNCSys.cnc_type = ""
        CNCSys.mt_type = ""
        CNCSys.series = ""
        CNCSys.version = ""
        CNCSys.axes = ""
```

I get the annoying message in the error list area (Because I´m not initializing the variables from the struct):

**"Warning Variable 'CNCSys' is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. Make sure the structure or all the reference members are initialized before use"**

Ok, adding that code solves the warning of non-initialized variables, I can build the solution and run, it... however when the function `GetControlInfo` is called, I get this excception:

**"Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout"**

I believe it´s is because those variables are Char vars in the structure, and they have fixed lengths... and I´m not somehow initializing them with the same lengths they have in the struct definition...

What am I doing wrong here? How can I initialize them so the compiler don´t throw me messages about un-initialized variables but also I don´t have problems with the marshaling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The definition tells you how many chars each string should have, so try "  " instead of "" where SizeConst=2. Not sure if size is in bytes though, in that case try " ".

Do similarly for the SizeConst=4

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
CNCSys.addinfo = 0S
CNCSys.max_axis = 0S
CNCSys.cnc_type = {" "c, " "c}
CNCSys.mt_type = {" "c, " "c}
CNCSys.series = {" "c, " "c, " "c, " "c}
CNCSys.version = {" "c, " "c, " "c, " "c}
CNCSys.axes = {" "c, " "c}
```

Also,`GetControlInfo` needs an `As` clause.